# Display a code in every posts/pages on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've wrote this code to display a box with pageviews which is inside of the arrow button on the right side of every title, but the thing is, the counter is not counting pageviews on pages and I don't know why.
I added this code in index.php

I tried to put my code for pageviews inside of `<?php is_singular( $post_types ); ?>` like this:

```
<?php is_singular(
    <div class="square">
    <div class="pageviews-icon"></div>
    <div class="pageviews"><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?></div>
</div>
); ?>
```

but is not working, the site crashed. Can anybody help me with this?

**Here's the code above this as well, maybe it could help and I could wrap all together**

```
<div class="frame">
                        <!-- uses the post format -->
                        <?php {
                            if(!get_post_format()) {
                               get_template_part('format', 'standard');
                            } else {
                               get_template_part('format', get_post_format());
                            };
                        ?>
                            <div class="square">
                                <div class="pageviews-icon"></div><div class="pageviews"><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?></div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

The website: [The link for the website](http://experiencias.freeserver.me/)

**Here's the pageview code too:**

```
    function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 Unique Views";
    }
    return $count.' Unique Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

Comment: The syntax you want is `<?php if (is_singular()) : ?> <!--Your HTML --> <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: I have tried every response option, even combine some parts of the responses, but I'm still not able to fix it :\

Comment: @Chun please accept an answer as your solution if possible, as this issue is so similar to my case. thanks

Comment: @bijibuji I've posted an answer to my question a couple of minutes ago, I was looking on the wrong part of the my code.

Comment: @Chun, thanks, but I think part of your answer is captured from other users answers. By the way its nice to give them up-votes, if their answer helped you achieve your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out were the code were messing up thanks to @RobSchmuecker, I was looking for bugs on the wrong place until he tells me about other pages so then I looked into all this code to see his statement, and I discovered where the code were messing up which was on a very bottom of a code page where I set it up the php views counter **which the code was:**

```
<?php if(is_single ()) { ?>
    <?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

**instead of:**

```
<?php if(is_singular ()) { ?>
    <?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

With many many hours of digging in code and trying stuff, I completly forgot about this part of the code. Thanks to all for helping me on this

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) says:

> This conditional tag checks if a singular post is being displayed, which is the case when one of the following returns true: is_single(), is_page() or is_attachment(). If the $post_types parameter is specified, the function will additionally check if the query is for one of the post types specified.

You should do it like this:

```
<?php if is_singular() { ?>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="pageviews-icon"></div>
        <div class="pageviews"><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?></div>
    </div>
<?php }; ?>
```

**Edit**
You have to do some changes to your css:

```
div.frame{position:relative;}
div.square{display:block;}
```

Your view counter is functional. too see it live, please correct your php code as I mentioned above

live on your site :
[image]

Comment: not sucessful :\ I also tried this but with `<?php endif; ?>` at the final, but didn't worked as well

Comment: @Chun After visiting your website, I think problem is resolved, Check my Edit

Comment: yeah, that's where I was looking for, but when I end the php like that `<?php } ?>` and I ftp it, it gives me a full blank page, because I need to close it as `<?php endif; ?>` because there's more php code below.

but where do I close the `}` ?

Do I close it like this? `<?php endif; } ?>`

Comment: php `if` statements have some different decorations. If you regard one, you can not combine it with another. I just prefer the `C` notation as: if(CONDITION){ DO THIS STUFF };

Comment: I tried to do as you told me to do, it keeps appearing the blank page, than I just added only the CSS to check if were any changes made but the button just desapeared. thanks for your help anyways mate

Comment: @Chun you can email me credentials to login and have a look if you want on arash.kianinasab[at]yahoo.com

Comment: @Chun see my last edit (addedd screenshot of your live website)

Comment: The counter for the posts is counting properly, the thing is on the pages, the counter on the pages is always the same

Comment: I think your question is not clear enough. please edit your question to fit your exact needs and mention exactly what is your expectations

Comment: I edited it and I've put the code above it too, maybe it can help. I want the counter to work too in the pages, that's why I was triyng the `<?php if is_singular() { ?>` to make the counter count for every page. Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put HTML in PHP. You can put STRINGS in PHP, but they need to be put in quotes.

```
if(is_single() || is_page() || is_attachment()) {
    ?>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="pageviews-icon"></div>
        <div class="pageviews"><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I have tried every response option, even combine some parts of the responses, but I'm still not able to fix it :\

I just added the pageview code too

Comment: @Chun you have to store your count in a database. Everytime the page is reloaded `$count` will start over. The internet is stateless, meaning everytime a page is served it's like it's starting over.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to do this in the file where you are looping through all your posts.  This can be in different locations depending on your theme etc .

For the twentyfourteen theme this is in index.php and looks like this

PHP

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
..... code carries on
```

The last line here: `get_template_part` tells us that it's pulling in a template called `content` if we go and open `content.php` we can see that this is where it actually outputs things specific for each page/post.  This is where you will need to do your logic.
So for example, instead of this in twentyfourteen `content.php`

PHP:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php if ( in_array( 'category', get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type() ) ) && twentyfourteen_categorized_blog() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <span class="cat-links"><?php echo get_the_category_list( _x( ', ', 'Used between list items, there is a space after the comma.', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php
            endif;

            if ( is_single() ) :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            else :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
            endif;
        ?>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php
                if ( 'post' == get_post_type() )
                    twentyfourteen_posted_on();

                if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) :
            ?>
            <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '1 Comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
            <?php
                endif;

                edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyfourteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

You would do something like this

PHP:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>

<header class="entry-header">
    <?php if ( in_array( 'category', get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type() ) ) && twentyfourteen_categorized_blog() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <span class="cat-links"><?php echo get_the_category_list( _x( ', ', 'Used between list items, there is a space after the comma.', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php
        endif;

        if ( is_single() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
        endif;
    ?>
        <div class="square">
        <div class="pageviews-icon"></div>
        <div class="pageviews"><?php echo getPostViews(the_ID()); ?></div>

    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php
            if ( 'post' == get_post_type() )
                twentyfourteen_posted_on();

            if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) :
        ?>
        <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '1 Comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
        <?php
            endif;

            edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyfourteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

and then make sure that your `getPostViews` is accessible in your `functions.php` file.

This will make sure that your `postViews` are being displayed.   But how to count them in the first place right?!

Go back to the `content.php` and have a look at this part of the code

PHP:

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfourteen' ) . '</span>',
                'after'       => '</div>',
                'link_before' => '<span>',
                'link_after'  => '</span>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The `is_search()` function says whether to display Excerpts for Search, home, category and tag pages.  However we don't want to set a pageview each time the post shows up in the search or home etc, so we must only put the `setPostViews` call in the other part of that `if` i.e. when the post/page is being viewed on its own.

That'll give you code like this

PHP:

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <!-- Now we can add a pageview -->
    <?php setPostViews(the_ID()); ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfourteen' ) . '</span>',
                'after'       => '</div>',
                'link_before' => '<span>',
                'link_after'  => '</span>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Again making sure that `setPostViews` is accessible in your `functions.php` file.

This should get you what you want.